# Slow consumer detection in Apache Qpid, but why?

Tags: qpid

I found that Apache Qpid has a function that detects slow consumers and disconnect them.

It means that if I have slow connectivity to queue or long think-time, I would never get service because I can burden the servers.

Has anyone perform experiments on this (Effect of slow consumers on QoS)?

Comment: At the time of consuming, you can increase the consuming time to **n** seconds. the default time is **2 minutes ** for the **consume()**.

Comment: Every 8 seconds, the broker will give a **fire ping** to itself, to check all the queues and exchanges, connections are fine or not. if it misses the continuous 3 pings, the broker will disconnect the consumes assuming that it's Dead.